# Where can you download functional domain labels of the human genome?

Tags: genome, database, data-download, public-dataset, functional-annotation

I'm visualizing where mutations occur in a gene, and would like to add functional domains to the plots.

I have some trouble locating sources to download data on functional domains.

The dataset should contain:

- Functional domain name
- Start position in gene
- End position in gene
- Gene symbol name

Any tips kindly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [GFF3 annotations](https://www.gencodegenes.org/human/) of the human genome.

If what you want is *protein domain annotations*, you may be more interested in the [UniProt database](https://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/genome_annotation_tracks/) which does seem to include [genome annotation tracks](https://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/genome_annotation_tracks/UP000000589_10090_beds/) for different protein functional regions.

I am unclear if uniprot directly has the gene names but this would be trivial to generate with a `bedtools intersect` operation.